# AngularJS: Understanding $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess

Tags: angularjs, redirect, angular-routing

I am working on a login page, on success, it redirect to home page. By default I show login page this code:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
      $location.url("/login");
  });
});
```

Then after validating the user/pass details from the backend I take the user to the home page:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    if ($scope.username === 'admin' && $scope.password === 'pass') {
      console.log('successful')
      $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
          $location.url("/home")
      });
      $location.url("/blah");
    } else {
      $scope.loginError = "Invalid username/password combination";
      console.log('Login failed..')
    };
  };
```

The redirect doesn't seem to work if I remove the second `$location.url` before the `else` section of the `if` statement. It is however not using that url (`/blah`), it goes to `home`. but If url `blah` is removed it the redirect logic does not work.

I can't seem to understand why I have to use two `$location.url()`. I would appretiate if someone can help me understand how this redirect system works?

This might not be the best practice, I am open to suggestions on how to improve this, here is [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/N0F0pM?p=preview)

Comment: what I can recommend you know is load in firebug and put breakpoints where u have questions. Also Network pane in Firebug shows all HTTP requests which can be very helpful.

Comment: what's up with all the `if (true)` statements?

Comment: @BorisIvanov no HTTP requests made, since I am redirecting to a partial.

Comment: But partial should also be downloaded.

Comment: @DavinTryon thanks for pointing that out, sample code is edited.

Comment: Well if I remove `$location.url( "/blah" );` there is no HTTP activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All in all this is going down a wrong path IMO...

Obviously you need to lock down any resources server side as client side can always be "changed" in a simple debugger... But I guess you already know that...

Alternative routing solutions like https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-routing or https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router IMO gives you some better handles for this, but lets just evaluate some approaches...

One would be: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZUKB1v?p=preview Although that requires you resolve the user on all routes... So.. :(... 
Another would be: http://plnkr.co/edit/iM9cA1?p=preview which might be a little better...

Finally, what people often seem to do is provide http interceptors that redirects to the login page when a "Unauthorized" error code is returned from the server. But this could seem to be a more advanced approach than your ready for.