# AngularJS simple Loginform

Tags: angularjs

I've just started to build a prototype in AngularJs/Bootstrap. I'm new to angular but it seem interesting enough to evaluate for some upcoming webprojects.
Step 1 would be to get some simple Loginform to work with hardcoded values and not bother to communicate with the backend service.

However, I read a bunch of tutorials but can't get the routing to work, the mysterious variable $location is always undefined no matter how many times I pass it around. Is perhaps the use of it old-fashioned? I tried some examples from this site but none works, $location is'nt among us anymore it seems?
Last example I tried:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
controller('loginController', ['$scope', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
      $scope.auth = function() {
          //check something useful
          $location.url('/view2');
      };
}])
```

If someone has a simple and working example (or an url for a trusted source of information) of a form and a controller that use routing to another partial, I would be delighted.

Regards

Comment: post the code where $location is not working, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
      $scope.auth = function() {
          //check something useful
          $location.url('/view2');
      };
}])
```

Each resource you want to inject into your controller should be passed as a string in the array.

Comment: Oh, that's simple and nice. Guess I'm getting confused by all the examples on the web, often with a different layout then "angular-seed" project. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I have been struggling with the same issue. I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833588/angularjs-understanding-rootscope-onroutechangesuccess). The answer shed some light. I was then able to **force** users to login and only then will they be able to access other links on the navbar. ***Then I had the issue of nav bar being visible on the login screen***. So I created a work-around:

1) I split the pages: using `ng-include` I was able to load `login.html` by default. `login.html` and `index.html` does not have `ng-view`.

2) Once the user is authenticated, `ng-view` must be inlcuded so that all views required on the navigation can work

**index.html**

```
   <html ng-app="plunker">

      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <div ng-include="template.url"></div>
      </body>

</html>
```

**login.html**

```
<h1>Login Page</h1>

<form ng-submit="login(username, password)">
  <label>User name</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="username" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" ng-model="password" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <br/>
  {{loginError}}  {{loggedUser}}
  <br/><br/>
  <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="">Submit</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Then if authentication passes I change templates (`ng-include`) and make `home.html` the default page

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, authentication) {
  $scope.templates =
  [
    { url: 'login.html' },
    { url: 'home.html' }
  ];
    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
  $scope.login = function (username, password) {
    if ( username === 'admin' && password === '1234') {
        authentication.isAuthenticated = true;
        $scope.template = $scope.templates[1];
        $scope.user = username;
    } else {
        $scope.loginError = "Invalid username/password combination";
    };
  };

};
```

Home.html has `ng-view` which will do the usual and the user has access to other pages.

This is what I have so far, here is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/8rUUtF?p=preview), hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting indeed, I will have a closer look for sure, thanks

Comment: I need complete login functionality like if existed user allow them to login if not redirect them to the registration page if users forget their password allow them to reset the password using OTP to the mobile number.